# Wordpress menus with submenu in other place

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would love to use wordpress built in menu system and I need sub-menus. Is it possible to on hover show that menu items sub-menu in other place. See image.
[image]

Thank you. Any suggestions how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the Sub-menu via the CMS in the menu panel dinamically under the parent label. Then you can just hide it onload and show it on the parent's hover. However the sub-menu must have `position: absolute` and, given your example the `li`would have to de displayed `inline`.
A sample code would be useful to sort out details but this should work.

Comment: Is it possible to detect if custom page template is used?

Comment: It depends no the theme but a `class`might be added to the body like a `page` or `single` or a custom `class` to one of the containers. You should check the `page`or `single` php file. Then you can style that class individually.